# How to keep spaces at the beginning of a formula

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to allign the formula text field under the label correctly with leading spaces.

Comment: In Formula field that combine text and graphics the label in the list view of the object is longer than the field text. I would like to add preceeding spaces to center the field test.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Unicode's 0xA0 (no-break space) character directly in a formula to provide spacing:

```
"Hello     World"
```

Renders as: "Hello     World"

You'll want to copy and paste this symbol directly from the example above, or from your favorite character map program.

Comment: excellent! yep, and leave notes in the formula field description as otherwise the next poor admin may have no idea what you did :-)

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce seems to strip out the blank spaces at the start and end of the string. Try using BR() function to add a line break at the begginning of the field